# Java: How To Use Arrays

Tags: java, arrays

I was learning about arrays today in school, and I am trying to do this problem, but cannot figure it

```
// Fortune Teller

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JButton;

public class FortuneTeller extends JFrame
    implements ActionListener
{
  private static final EasySound ding = new EasySound("ding.wav");

  // Declare an array of "fortunes" (strings):
  ___________________________________________
  ...

  private JTextField display;

  public FortuneTeller()
  {
    super("Fortune Teller");

    display = new JTextField("  Press \"Next\" to see your fortune...", 25);
    display.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    display.setEditable(false);

    JButton go = new JButton("Next");
    go.addActionListener(this);

    Container c = getContentPane();
    c.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    c.add(display);
    c.add(go);
  }

  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
  {
    // Pick and display a random fortune:

    ___________________________________________
    ...

    display.setText("  " + __________________ );
    ding.play();
  }

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    JFrame window = new FortuneTeller();
    window.setBounds(300, 300, 300, 100);
    window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    window.setResizable(false);
    window.setVisible(true); 
  }
}
```

I am trying to fill in the blanks.

For the first one,, would it just be just be String [] Fortune;?

But how would I end up initializing it?

And then for the second part, what would I have to do?

Please help as I am extremely lost.

Comment: Read this up: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

Answer (score 3):

Here are some hints to help you (without actually doing your homework for you).

You can create and populate an array of strings in one line using the following syntax:

```
String[] colours = {"Red", "Orange", "Yellow", "Green", "Blue", "Indigo", "Violet"};
```

You can generate a random number between zero and x (inclusive) using the following syntax:

```
int randomNumber = Math.random() * (x + 1);
```

You can select a random string from an array with the following syntax:

```
String randomColour = colours[Math.random() * colours.length];
```

Answer (score 2):

As found by the simple Google search "How to declare an array in Java":

```
String[] fortune = {"You're going to be right","You're going to die","You're going to find a cat"};
```

This also initializes the array.

Then to get the an element of the array, you do:

```
fortune[1];

//Returns: You're going to die
```

For this though, I'd do a random number generator to pick a number between 0 and the length of the array:

```
int value = Math.random() * fortune.length; 
fortune[value];
```

Comment: Do you know how to choose a random element from the list? I was trying to find stuff and got the following:                                                   int idx = new Random().nextInt(fruits.length);
    String random = (fruits[idx]);

    display.setText("  " + random );

Comment: @ConfusedCoder I showed you how to get a random element.

Comment: Oh. Didn't that there *embarrassment*